# How to capture the mouse events in quip.apps.ui.RichTextBox

Tags: liveapps

For quip RichTextBox i saw only handlekeyevent and how to capture the mouse events? I set an character limit for the richtextbox by using HandleKeyEvent and i try to copy paste text with more than character limit  through mouse it accepts because i am not handling mouse events.Is there any way to capture Mouse events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onFocus` and `onBlur` should work in this case (and then you can truncate using `setTextContent`)